# ResNet preprocessing function not implemented?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I wanted to implement a pretrained ResNet in my Framework. For that, I want to use the ResNet-18. Since it is not available on Keras I used the one on Github: https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models

I was wondering if the preprocessing of the Input even does anything with that implementation since the preprocessing function for the ResNet models is implemented like this:

```
def preprocess_input(x, **kwargs):
    return x
```

Since I want to use the ResNet to extract features, shouldn't the images need to be preprocessed before I feed them to the network?

Comment: nope just specify your input shape

Comment: Is this normal with the ResNet models? Don´t they need some kind of preprocessing step, they used for training on ImageNet?

Comment: not for images, that would be case for some pretrained NLP models like Bert..